Difficulty in logging and error reporting
Basically I have to write a function in pytest-idf which has to print numbers and their squares. If the numbers and their sq. dont match, it should raise an exception and throw an error and record all the numbers for which it fails.
I can not figure out how to record the numbers for which it fails.
I have written a code in c for my esp32s3 and a code in python to test for errors.
I want a pytest_embedded_idf code fore which the above works. Thanks
